# Writing to new row in excel using openpyxl each time program run

Tags: python, selenium, openpyxl

I am new to python and I am trying to automate using python selenium. I am trying to store values in excel from a report by running the selenium python script every 30 mins. Each time I run the script, I need to store following values: Date in column A, Time in column B, Percentage values from report in Column C, Valid values from report in column D and so on.

Below is my script and you can see from my first run of script, I was able to store values in row 2 and it's working fine.

How can I store values in row 3, row 4 and so on from 2nd run, 3rd run... of script? Can someone help on this?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r"C:\MyFolder\Filename.xlsx"

TodaysDate = time.strftime("%b%d")
sheet_name = TodaysDate.upper()

wb = load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb[sheet_name]

Date = time.strftime(("%b%d"))

sheet.cell(row=2, column=1).value = Date

Time = time.strftime("%I%M")

sheet.cell(row=2, column=2).value = Time

PCTCLOSE = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Percentage Close')]").text

sheet.cell(row=2, column=3).value = PCTCLOSE

ValidResponse = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(text(),'Valid 
Response')]").text

sheet.cell(row=2, column=4).value = ValidResponse

wb.save(path)
```

Comment: Check the docs for openpyxl... there should be a call for max_row which will tell you the number of rows in the sheet.  Alternatively you can load all data into an array, append the array with new data, and then write out the whole excel file again.

Comment: I couldn’t find any that helps in openpy documents. Can someone help me here please.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find the information you need in the openpyxl docs, a simple search of "openpyxl max row" should bring up the page you need (link to the relevant page in the docs [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.max_row)). Below is a modified version of your code that should do what you want

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = r"C:\MyFolder\Filename.xlsx"

TodaysDate = time.strftime("%b%d")
sheet_name = TodaysDate.upper()

wb = load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb[sheet_name]
# Find last row of written data
row = sheet.max_row + 1

# Writing your data at the bottom
Date = "foo"
Time = "bar"
PCTCLOSE = "foo"
ValidResponse = "bar"
sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = Date
sheet.cell(row=row, column=2).value = Time
sheet.cell(row=row, column=3).value = PCTCLOSE
sheet.cell(row=row, column=4).value = ValidResponse

wb.save(path)
```